# Want to Use Whisper in My Flutter Project and Not Sure Where to Start

Tags: python, flutter, cross-platform, openai-whisper

First I'd like to say that I know similar questions about calling Python code in Flutter have been asked before, but I think this particular case has some challenges.

Some notes about the app I'm aiming for:
Basically a note taking app, records a lecture or meeting or whatever and transcribes the text for you, with a few extra features thrown in. I'd like to have all speech being processed locally both to ensure it works offline and reduce the app's dependence on cloud services.

I'm trying to use [Whisper](https://github.com/openai/whisper), a new speech to text software that processes everything locally, which is a necessity for my app. I know I could make a Flutter plugin but I'm not sure if that's the best route to go about this for a few reasons:

1. I haven't done it before, so it would be quite a time investment to do this and just hope it works out.
2. One of the ways I've seen of doing this involves sending data over http between Python and Flutter, but Whisper would need a continuous stream of audio to work properly which I'm not sure this approach is suited for.
3. I'd really like to have 1 codebase that runs on any device.

I'd be fine with the app only working on pc for now, but I'd like to also have it working on Android and maybe IOS if reasonably possible. Any other routes I can take towards development are great too but I'd really like to stick with Flutter for this app if I can.

Answer (score 0):

Just found that one: https://github.com/azkadev/whisper_dart

Did not tried it until now but seems to be worth the try.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Didn't managed to get it to work on MacOS with Whisper_dart. Have you?